# How can I establish a transfer function for an optocoupler + amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, analog, opto-isolator

I have a simple analog circuit which takes a large reference voltage and outputs an isolated, small, scaled voltage.

I am trying to establish the transfer function for the circuit for calibration purposes.

The optoisolator, [HCNR200](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/HCNR200-HCNR201-High-Linearity-Analog-Optocouplers-DS), has a transfer gain of 1. The op-amp is an [OPA197](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa197.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The transfer function is as follows:

Vout = (((Vin/R1)/K1)xK2)xR2)

Due to equal K factors and identical resistors of 51kOhm, the transfer function is simply the voltage divider output:

Vout = Vin x (7500/7500+499000+499000)

Therefore, BRG_COPTO = 0.00746 x ACREF